# run command at interval on debian

Tags: linux, debian, cron

So i have a debian web mapping server for my minecraft world. In order for the map to display the correct information two commands have to be run periodically. I have tried following a few guides to use crontab but so far have failed (and even had to restore the debian image -.-) I am new to linux as a whole and need a step by step guide in plain english to do the following.

run:

```
"overviewer.py --config /home/mc/test.cfg"
```

every 30 minutes on the hour and

```
"overviewer.py --config /home/mc/test.cfg --genpoi"
```

every five minutes on the hour

It seems pretty straight forward but I have literally spent the better part of two months doing this cause I keep screwing things up.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember if you are using crontab, to use the full path to the python script. In debian you can type *pwd* in the terminal to show the path to your current location.

Assuming the python script is also located in */home/mc/* you should use the command:

```
/home/mc/overviewer.py --config /home/mc/test.cfg
```

I would suggest you look into crontab again, the ubuntu help page has alot of information. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

For every 30 minutes:

```
0,30 * * * * /home/mc/overviewer.py --config /home/mc/test.cfg
```

And for every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/mc/overviewer.py --config /home/mc/test.cfg --genpoi
```

Comment: this worked quite well, the link you gave me was extreamly helpful as well, just wish i found that sooner. in this case however the command worked properly without defining the location of overviewer.py, i assume this is because it is installed as a system package but i am not 100% sure of that